# Using Scrapy to get images

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy have tried to create a new project using the command line (in Scrapy resource, and several forums), have installed the Scrapy module but it is not working.

It seems so simple.

Thank you.

```
import scrapy

scrapy startproject myproject
```

And I get:

```
File "C:/XX/1822197263.py", line 1
scrapy startproject myproject
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have to run `scrapy startproject myproject` in console/terminal, not in code - and it should generate all needed folders and files.

Comment: if you see lines with `$` at the beginning (like in examples on [main page](https://scrapy.org/)) then it means you have to run it in console/terminal

Comment: at start you may run `scrapy` without  creating project - you can put all in one file and use `CrawlerProcess()` in code to start scraping. One of example [How to scrape alloschool.com with scrapy](https://blog.furas.pl/python-scaping-how-to-scrape-alloschool.com-with-scrapy.html), more on blog or in my repo on GitHub: [furas / python-examples / scraping](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__)

Comment: to get images scrapy has special objects [Image Pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html?highlight=imagepipeline#using-the-images-pipeline) which download file or images